# Getting "iteration not started" when using UpdateCursor / deleteRow()?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.1, cursor

I'm attempting to delete some features from a feature class using an `arcpy.da.UpdateCursor`. The line `uc.deleteRow()` throws an exception with the message `iteration not started`.

The `where_clause` is "item_no in (123,456,789)"; return records with a value in this field found in this comma-delimited list. Here is the where clause being passed in `ITEM_NO in (1,8,9)`.

To remove the `where_clause` as a possible source of this problem, I hard-coded a single value into the where; "item_no = 123". This also threw the error.

If I change this to a `searchCursor` using the same parameters, three records are returned, as expected.

```
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc, "OBJECTID", where_clause=strWhere) as uc:
    for row in XYZ:
        try:
            uc.deleteRow()
        except Exception, e:
            print e
```

What am I doing wrong and how do I get around this?

Comment: uc.deleteRow(row)   I think you actually need to pass the row as a parameter to the deleteRow method.

Comment: @GeoJohn - I just tried that. `deleteRow() takes no arguments (1 given)`

Comment: I'd lose the try/except while you are trying to debug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `UpdateCursor` is called `uc` but you're iterating through `XYZ`

```
for row in XYZ:
```

As a result it hasn't started iterating through your cursor to be able to delete anything.  You need to reference your cursor:

```
for row in uc:
```

Comment: This is why you should be verbose in your variable naming. I feel the examples of ArcObjects don't always provide a good example of this.